# Need restart tomcat for html changes

Tags: java, spring-mvc, gradle, thymeleaf, tomcat8

I am working with eclipse in a project that is running with tomcat 8. I am using Spring MVC + Thymeleaf. I have the war plugin in Gradle, so each time I change a java class, it automatically creates the new WAR file and deploy it in tomcat.

The problem is that when I change an HTML file, I have to restart tomcat to see the changes. Something that doesn't happend with another project with JSF where if I change an xhtml, I can see the new stuff just refreshing the browser.

The question is, does I have to restart Tomcat each time I change an HTML or CSS file? it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Can you find out how HTML files are placed in a project? HTML files can be managed as resources by different approaches and maybe it could be the root cause of problem.

Comment: @sphinks my HTML files are placed under WebContent/WEB-INF/templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was Thymeleaf cache. You can disable it in the configuration with `setCacheable`. This is valid for Thymeleaf 3+:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding(UTF8);
    return viewResolver;
}

private TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    return engine;
}

private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resolver.setCacheable(false);
    return resolver;
}
```

I found this in this [answer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34#issuecomment-68209652) in a Spring-boot thread.

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable cacheble when you configure the template engine

```
<bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    ...
    <property name="cacheable" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Let me know if this worked for you

Comment: Yes! The problem was Thymeleaf cache, buy I have java configuration. I have posted it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `exploded war`. If you use `.war` file you need redeploy for every change (As I know).